# How to send file using request?

Tags: node.js, python-requests

I am trying to hit an API which I got as a curl request. But When I am trying to upload it throwing an error that file is not uploaded. This is my curl request which is working fine.

> curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/zip" --data-binary @/Users/aitplap24/Desktop/WebGIS/uploads/users/61adbbe3ececf2068d6eb862/1638776276622.zip  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/61adbbe3ececf2068d6eb862/datastores/layer1/61a604021467d3152d5720fa.shp

Here is my NodeJS code for doing the same using requests

```
const url = process.env.GEOSERVER_URL;
    var headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/zip'
    };
    var dataString = '@/Users/aitplap24/Desktop/WebGIS/uploads/users/61adbbe3ececf2068d6eb862/1638776276622.zip';

    var options = {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/61adbbe3ececf2068d6eb862/datastores/test1/file.shp',
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: headers,
        body: dataString,
        formData : {
            "file" : fs.createReadStream("/Users/aitplap24/Desktop/WebGIS/uploads/users/61adbbe3ececf2068d6eb862/1638776276622.zip")
        },
        auth: {
            'user': 'admin',
            'pass': 'geoserver'
        }
    };

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log(error, response, body);
    });
```

Error which I am getting

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
```

I am sure something I am doing wrong with file uploading. Any suggestions is of great help!

Comment: you are uploading a file so it should be a post request

Comment: No it should be PUT request. Check my curl